# Array of data being printed as one column in Excel using Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, export-to-excel

I have tried so many ways, but couldn't fix it. When I run, the output is I can download the file. However, all the columns are combined into one cell and printed out as one line.

```
 download(){

      const vm = this
      let item = vm.dataItems;
      let data = [];
      
      for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
         data.push({
                "Movement Code": item[i].insurancemovtypedesc,
                "Employee Name": item[i].staffname,
                "Employee ID Type": this.emptypeid,
                "Employee IC No / Passport No": item[i].stafficno,
                "Relationship": item[i].relationship,
                "Gender": item[i].depgender,
                "Date of Birth": moment(item[i].depdob).format("DD-MM-YYYY"),
                "Nationality Code": item[i].depnationality,
                "Member Name": item[i].dependentname,
                "Member ID Type": this.emptypeid,
                "Member IC No / Passport No": item[i].depicno,
                "Effective Date":item[i].movdate,
                "Employee ID": item[i].staffcode,
                "Occupation": item[i].posdesc,
                "Employee Category": item[i].gtlcoveragevalue,
                "Monthly Salary": item[i].basicsal,
                "GHS Plan": item[i].ghscoveragevalue,
                "OutPatient Plan": item[i].outpatientcoveragevalue,
               
         });
       }
       

          const csvData = this.abcd(data);
           this.abc(csvData);
      },
             //  this.newdownload1();

          // let itemNew = this.formData;
          // let item2 = this.dataItems

          // this.$router.push({name: "exportstaffinsurancelog", params: {itemNew, item2}, });
  

  abcd(data){
     const xlsRows = [];

      // get header
      const headers = Object.keys(data[0]);
      xlsRows.push(headers);
     

      // loop over the rows
      for (const row of data) {
       
        const values = headers.map((header) => {
          const escaped = ("" + row[header]).replace(/"/g, '\\"');
          return `${escaped}`;

        });
        
         xlsRows.push(values);
    
      }
    
      return xlsRows.join("\n");

  },

  abc(data){

     // const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'});

      const blob = new Blob([data], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});


      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      const a = document.createElement("a");

      a.setAttribute("hidden", "");
      a.setAttribute("href", url);
      a.setAttribute('download', "Staff Insurance Records" + ".xls");

      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      document.body.removeChild(a);
  },
```

This is the Excel output:

[image: this is the excel output]

Comment: can you please add a code instead of screenshot

Comment: @RohìtJíndal I have added the code now